# istio integration with docker desktop

Tags: istio, docker-desktop, istio-gateway

I followed the example mentioned in Istio setup (in docker desktop)
[here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/#determining-the-ingress-ip-and-ports). I am not able to connect to service.

URL I am trying:

```text
curl -s -I  "http://localhost:80/status/200"
```

Below is the Virtual service and gateway for above example mentioned in link:

```text
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: httpbin-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: httpbin
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - httpbin-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /status
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 8000
        host: httpbin
```

```text
>kubectl get svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system
NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                      AGE
istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   10.110.230.106   localhost     15021:32117/TCP,80:32577/TCP,443:32202/TCP   5d15h
```

```text
>curl -s -I "localhost:80/status/200" -v
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD /status/200 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: Please include the output of `kubectl get svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system` in your question. Also what is the output of `curl` with `-v` flag (curl -v http://localhost:80/status/200`?

Comment: try using `127.0.0.1` istead of `localhost` - `curl -s -I  "http://127.0.0.1:80/status/200"`

Comment: Hi same response as with localhost                                                                            
curl -s -I  "http://127.0.0.1:80/status/200" -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD /status/200 HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact

Comment: Are you on windows?

Comment: yes, windows on docker dextop

Comment: Check the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file. There should be a line like `<ip-adress> host.docker.internal`. Use whatever is in `<ip-adress>` instead of `localhost`

Comment: No sucess, same outcome                                                                                                                           curl -s -I  "http://192.168.1.10:80/status/200" -v
*   Trying 192.168.1.10...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.1.10 (192.168.1.10) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD /status/200 HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.1.10
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.1.10 left intact